# typescript startup performance

Tags: node.js, typescript

The npm moudle `typescript` takes about 0.3 seconds to be imported.

Is this acceptable? How to optimize the performance?

index.js

```js
import 'typescript'
console.log(process.uptime())
```

```bash
node index.js
// output: 0.310505
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPT told me that there is a project called `SWC`,

and I put it in my code,

Shocking, damn fast! It's a magic!

```js
import swc from '@swc/core'

const { code } = await swc.transform(tsCode, {
                // filename: inputFile,
                sourceMaps: false,
                jsc: {
                    parser: {
                        syntax: "typescript",
                    },
                    target: 'esnext'
                },
                module: {
                    type: 'es6'
                }
            });
```